# Where is this function coming from and how to get rid of it?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, compiler

Last night there was an attempt to have CMake build a binary instead of the IDE. Got it to compile and spit out an .elf file, however I noticed when I was trying to compare the IDE .elf vs the CMake .elf I happened to spot a slight text section difference.

```
IDE .elf arm-none-eabi-size:
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   6516       8    1936    8460    210c xxx.elf

CMake .elf arm-none-eabi-size:
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   6912       8    1936    9547    254b xxx.elf
```

I futher investiagted and dissambled both and found theres 2 functions within the CMake .elf that the IDE .elf doesnt have, shown here:

```
    Disassembly of section .text:

080002a0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
 80002a0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (80002b0 <deregister_tm_clones+0x10>)
 80002a2:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (80002b4 <deregister_tm_clones+0x14>)
 80002a4:   4283        cmp r3, r0
 80002a6:   d002        beq.n   80002ae <deregister_tm_clones+0xe>
 80002a8:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (80002b8 <deregister_tm_clones+0x18>)
 80002aa:   b103        cbz r3, 80002ae <deregister_tm_clones+0xe>
 80002ac:   4718        bx  r3
 80002ae:   4770        bx  lr
 80002b0:   24000000    strcs   r0, [r0], #-0
 80002b4:   24000000    strcs   r0, [r0], #-0
 80002b8:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

080002bc <register_tm_clones>:
 80002bc:   4805        ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; (80002d4 <register_tm_clones+0x18>)
 80002be:   4906        ldr r1, [pc, #24]   ; (80002d8 <register_tm_clones+0x1c>)
 80002c0:   1a0b        subs    r3, r1, r0
 80002c2:   0fd9        lsrs    r1, r3, #31
 80002c4:   eb01 01a3   add.w   r1, r1, r3, asr #2
 80002c8:   1049        asrs    r1, r1, #1
 80002ca:   d002        beq.n   80002d2 <register_tm_clones+0x16>
 80002cc:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (80002dc <register_tm_clones+0x20>)
 80002ce:   b103        cbz r3, 80002d2 <register_tm_clones+0x16>
 80002d0:   4718        bx  r3
 80002d2:   4770        bx  lr
 80002d4:   24000000    strcs   r0, [r0], #-0
 80002d8:   24000000    strcs   r0, [r0], #-0
 80002dc:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

The target is a [STM32H743ZI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h743zi.html#:%7E:text=STM32H743ZI%20%2D%20High%2Dperformance%20and%20DSP,STM32%20High%20Performance%20MCUs) using arm-none-eabi-g++ & arm-none-eabi-gcc compilers. The project uses both C and C++

My question is, where the heck did this come from? How to get rid of it? and why does the CMake .elf does this whereas the IDE .elf doesnt?

Comment: There should be a "flag" to have *make* report spawned commands verbosely. There may be an equivalent facility in the IDE.

Comment: @greybeard Verbose for the make, or the linker, or both?

Comment: I'd first try to figure out which commands were started and all the ("command line") parameters used. more likely than not, some compiler driver (like *cc*) invoked the linker specifying one *runtime object* (like *crt0.o*).

Comment: @greybeard We did try doing that but couldnt find a difference in flags. Ill try it again and update you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are for [transactional memory support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libitm/C_002fC_002b_002b-Language-Constructs-for-TM.html). What they do is mentioned in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625934/11654).

Apparently, your IDE and the command-line compiler are different versions, or use different configurations. Try `--fno-gnu-tm` to disable it.

Comment: Holy, I have to try this thank you! Why would different versions add this in?

Comment: It might not yet have been supported in an earlier version. Or somebody decided that nobody is using it anyway.

Comment: Thank you, yes just confirmed the CMAKE .elf was compiled using 9.x compiler whereas the IDE .elf was using 10.3 compiler

Comment: Btw, just curious I am trying to find '--fno-gnun-tm' and cant seem to find it how did you know to use that?

Comment: The documentation mentions `--fgnu-tm`. You have to know that the `no-` prefix is possible for `--f` options.

Comment: I didnt know you could slap on no- prefix, is this true for all -f-xxx flags?

Comment: Yes; see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html.

Comment: Thank you good sir, and unrelated note nice user name (Same initials haha)

Comment: So, tested and updated each compiler to the same version (10.3), however a new issue as occur where in the .rodata for whatever reason has increased.

Comment: Just want to post this, the issue has been resolved by using the same matched compiler (10.3)